# Image Compression using WEBP_LOSSLSS sometimes increases the size of image instead of compressing it

Tags: java, android, bitmap, image-compression

`````````
````````for converting to bitmap
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                 BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView3.getDrawable();
                            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                            saveImage(bitmap);
`````````

---

> it compresses the image and save it in folder 'test'...

```
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    OutputStream fos;
             long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    String timestamp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(currentTime);
            try {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"Image"+timestamp+".jpg");
                            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpg");
                            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "test");
                            imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                            fos = (FileOutputStream) resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP_LOSSLESS, 100, fos);
                            Objects.requireNonNull(fos);
            
                            Toast.makeText(this,"Image saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
            
            
                    }
```

---

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null){
        
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    imageView3.setImageURI(imageUri);
  }
```

- Problems
- how do I solve the image size increase after compression problem?
- And Can I compress image to specific size lets say 500kb?

Comment: About wich sizes are you talking? You start with a bitmap and end up with a file.

Comment: And is there a way to use WEBP_LOSSLESS and compress images to specific kB size by taking input from user like.....there would be input box for taking int value...and the image will be compressed in that specific kb? Anybody know how to do it

Comment: Quote: `Filename extension
.webp[1]
Internet media type
image/webp`. Why dont you use those?

Comment: will it fix the problem for over sizing?

Comment: Okayy I am explaining with example.... I take image who's size is 6 mb and after compression image size goes to 10 mb idkw...

Comment: I see no images. I only see a bitmap and a file/imageUri.

Comment: Yaa because I have separate function for taking image from gallery and it would display in imageview

Comment: That all does not matter to give a good example. Choose one. Choose picking a file. And tell what you put in the bitmap as we have not a single idea. Add that code at the start of your other code.

Comment: Okayy... Will add the code for it in some time..

Comment: I have edited and Put the whole code that I have written

Comment: Please format your code as ity is a mess now. Further: Why post that much irrelevant code. I only asked to show what you loaded in the bitmap.

Comment: Actually I am new to this community....so I am still figuring out how to convey my problem....dw I will edit the Question....

Comment: okay....BEAR with me please....I have edited the code and I think its in format now but it says add some context to the section..and IDK how....sigh